# Reverse a string- run time error

Tags: c, string

I'm new to c programming and it is my first attempt at reversing a string. I entered the following code but got a run-time error. Could anyone please tell me where am I wrong so that I don't repeat the same mistake again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
# define size 10

int main()
{
    int i=0; int a=0;
    char s[size];
    printf("enter your word");
    scanf("%s", s);
    a= strlen(s);
    for(i=a-1;i>=0;--i)
    {printf("%s", s[i]);}

    return 0;
}
```

Thank You very much.

Comment: `%s` wants a C-string not a single char. You want `%c`.

Answer (score 2):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()`: `%s` calls for `char*`, but `s[i]` has type `char`. Use `%c` to print one character.

Also don't forget to add `#include <string.h>` in order to use `strlen()`.

Comment: I think it is an OT question. Suggestion could be done through comments.

Comment: Thank you. Got the output. One more thing, I edited scanf("%s", s) to scanf("%s" ,&s). Does it make any difference?

Comment: @VishakhaRamani It will invoke *undefined behavior* by passing pointer pointing to data having wrong type. `%s` expects `char*`, but the type of `&s` is `char (*)[10]`. Some compilers with proper option will warn about it.